# File shares are not deleted when Microsoft Teams meeting member is removed

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams

The following situation has occurred:

- A meeting was planned
- The automatically generated link was clicked
- The automatically created meeting chat was opened
- A file has been uploaded
- File is stored in the personal OneDrive and a share is automatically created for the meeting members
- A member was removed (Outlook -> person under "required" -> removed -> saved)
- Member has been removed from the meeting chat (also displays "Name has left the conversation")
- Now when I look at the file in my OneDrive, the remote employee still has access to the file

[image: microsoft teams]

Isn't it automatically removed? Are there any tricks, special features etc.?

Comment: Meeting participants can access the files shared during meeting chat, This is by design, if any member is removed they will not be able to send messages in chat & will not be able to access the content after they were removed

Comment: Apparently, you didn't read my entire article. The removed employee still has the right to view/edit my file, I can see it in my OneDrive... Of course, he can no longer click on the link to the file in the meeting. He no longer sees this meeting. But if he still has the URL to the file, he can still access my file.

Comment: Does those files shared when user was part of that meeting or it is shared after he left the conversation?

Comment: Those files were shared when the specific user was part of that meeting. (see screenshot)

Comment: Did you check microsoft website yet?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/user-access

Comment: @AntonioLabra In my opinion this is not helpful, my problem relates to access to a file by a user who has been removed from a meeting. The documentation on general user administration of Microsoft Teams does not help me.

Comment: This is by design, if user was part of meeting while file shared. He would be able to access the files which is shared during his time